# Copying table from one database to another

Tags: python, sql, pandas, amazon-s3, redhat

I'm trying to copy a table from an S3 server onto a Redhat server using python but it's not working. Any ideas?

As an initial restriction I can't create temp tables in the origin server, I can only copy onto my computer and upload from there.

To start I've tried creating an empty dataframe with pandas, appending chunks as to avoid memory issues like so, but I'm getting errors including (OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] Communication link failure (14) (SQLFetch)')):

```
connection1 = pyodbc.connect(XXXX)
query1 = 'SELECT * FROM table'
dfl = []  


for i in pd.read_sql(query1, con=connection1 ,chunksize=1000):
dfl.append(chunk)


downloaded_data = pd.concat(dfl, ignore_index=True)
```

I'm not really sure if this is the best approach so I'm really open to recommendations.

Comment: doesn't look like you were able to connect to SQL server.

Comment: Rather than selecting from each table, you'd typically use the database's backup and restore utilities.

Comment: Not sure about your connection issue but if you are concerned about memory issues I don't think appending all the data to a list of dataframes will help.  You could try to wirte to_sql within the for loop and append to the Redhat Table

Answer (score 0):

I did a Oracle migration database with many tables, but lost this code :-(

I basically create these steps:

- Connect the source database;
- Create a list of all the tables you want to migrate.
- For which table, you need to read a tab_column_name to extract a column name sequence table.
- Save the date in a dictionary
- Connect the target database (with the table created) and enter with the same string as you extracted;
- I recommend that you extract the script from all tables and create in target first
- to validate before extracting, save a row count table to match after insertion (do row count at destination)

My the tables have many dates and python gave me a good performance.

I hope this helps